# Embed all DLLs in win app and C#

Tags: c#, dll, embed, exe

I use this code to embed all dlls to app exe file but this code can embed only one dll. i search for other code but all are same that.

```
public App()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve +=new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}

System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string dllName = args.Name.Contains(',') ? args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) : args.Name.Replace(".dll","");

    dllName = dllName.Replace(".", "_");

    if (dllName.EndsWith("_resources")) return null;

    System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(GetType().Namespace + ".Properties.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    byte[] bytes = (byte[])rm.GetObject(dllName);

    return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes);
}
```

to use ILmerge i have problem wuth my dlls. so i cant use this.
how can i do this?

Comment: I use third party assemblies and want the users can't understand this.

Comment: You've already succeeded, I can't understand that.  If ILMerge fails then it is very likely that Assembly.Load(byte[]) will fail as well.  It cannot load DLLs that contain native code.  Package your executables in a single file called setup.exe, you create one with a Setup project.

Answer (score 0):

This open source tool should help you

http://madebits.com/netz/

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to add all your DLLs to resources (manually). Then, at the program's startup, use `File.WriteAllBytes` to write those resource byte streams to files.

**NOTE :** In this case you cannot use `DllImport`, since it requires constant string path. Instead, you will use what so called "dynamic P\Invoke". [Learn more.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/07/14/181932.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using GetManifestResourceStream should work better.

When the dlls are embedded as resources the resource names are prefixed with the default name space for you project, so you will need to fill that in.

eg

```
static  System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string defaultNameSpace = "...";

    string dllName = args.Name.Contains(',') ? args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) : args.Name.Replace(".dll", "");

    string resourceName = String.Format("{0}.{1}.dll", defaultNameSpace , dllName);

    using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
         if (stream == null)  
             return null;

         byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
         stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
         return Assembly.Load(data);
     }
 }
```